# Typescript type property based on a zod schema

Tags: typescript, types, zod

I have this type I want to define better.

```
type BaseFormProps = {
  className?: string;
  labelClassName?: string;
  inputClassName?: string;
  schema: Schema;
  children?: ReactNode;
  onChange?: (errors: Array<any>) => void;
  onSubmit: (data: any) => void;
}
```

I'm using Zod to create Schema and validate data.
I would like to change the type property `onSubmit: (data: any) => void;` to replace `any` with `z.infer<typeof X>` where X depends on the value of the schema property.

Is it possible to reference a specific key of a type definition inside this type definition ?

Answer (score 0):

Given that `Schema` is some zod schema type definition, you can define a generic type that accepts some zod schema as the type parameter and derives the input type to your `onSubmit` callback function using `z.infer`. For example:

```js
import { z } from "zod";

type Props<T extends z.ZodTypeAny> = {
  schema: T;
  onSubmit: (val: z.infer<T>) => void;
};

// A concrete schema for the example
const schema = z.object({
  a: z.string(),
});

// Some code that uses the generic type
function example(props: Props<typeof schema>) {
  const data: unknown = { a: "cat" };
  const parsed = props.schema.parse(data);
  props.onSubmit(parsed);
}

// Example of using the above code
example({
  schema,
  // Here the callback type is refined to `{ a: string }` based
  // on the value that `schema` parses
  onSubmit: ({ a }) => console.log(a),
});
```

The crux of this solution is `ZodTypeAny` which is a helper type from zod which can be used to stand in for "some schema" in generic types. When you realize the type (in the `example` function this is done with `Props<typeof schema>`) the types will be narrowed to the specific type that your given schema parses.

See [the documentation on writing generic functions](https://zod.dev/?id=writing-generic-functions) for more details about this approach

Comment: It doesn't work as Schema is a generic type for Zod Schema and the type of the `schema` property is a compiled Zod schema.

Comment: I see, you want to use the parsed type in your callback function but pass in the schema used to parse that type. I'll update my answer